How to copy a image in a jupyter notebook markdown cell that already encode as base64
I was working with a juypter notebook with vs code. Then there is a markdown cell with a iamge. I want to copy this cell to another notebook, but when i use copy cell and paste cell command, the markdown text was there，but the image can't be displayed.
I found that the image already encode as base64 format and saved in the file.
How to copy this base64 data while copying this cell.
Thanks!

This doesn't answer why VSCode cannot do it; however, this is easy in current JupyterLab. You can demonstrate it for yourself. Go here and click the 'launch binder' badge. The session that comes up is running on a remote temporary system, and so you'll need to add your notebook that has what you want to move to a new notebook. For demonstration, drag-and-drop the notebook from your local computer's file browsing system into the file navigation panel on the left side of the session. It should upload ...

 and become listed there. Now click on it to open the notebook in JupyterLab and then open a new notebook. They'll open stacked. You want to arrange them side-by-side for easy editing/dragging. So click on the new notebook's tab along the top where the notebook's name is and hold down the mouse button and drag it over to the right in the main panel and it should highlight in blue you can place it side by side, and at that point you can release the mouse to let it adopt that arrangement. (You should get a sense of how to arrange in general by seeing ...

 here for a video demonstrating that.) Now with two notebooks side-by-side you are ready to drag and drop individual cells or selections of multiple cells. Start with one cell that has an image as an attachment embedded in markdown and click it to select it. Then hover in the cell to the left of the blue bar on the right, but to the left of the cell itself. You should see a set of crossroads of arrows symbol pop up. Now click there and hold down the mouse button and drag and ...

 drop the cell over to the New Notebook you opened. It will copy it. Save the notebook and you should be able to open it in the editor and see it copied the cell with the image embedded. Download anything good you make in the session immediately because the remote computer is only temporary. You can do the same after you select multiple notebooks cells by holding down the shift key as you select. It can be tricky because you have to go back up to the top of the selection to get the movement symbol to come up when you hover. That is how you can easily do this is  modern JupyterLab.

You could also do this programmatically in VSCode by scripting with nbformat.
